# ajax/php/mysql shopping cart project

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Designing a simple shopping cartt project in which the user is presented a mysql database "items" displaying an assortment of items in a php page. I have designed 2 tables in the database one called items and the other called cart, cart is currently empty as the page will add data to it accordingly, its columns are as follows: "cust_id" (short for customer id, is primary key), "item" (related to selected item by user from items table, also primary key), and "qty" (quantity also user defined in the next table)

The items database is composed of 4 columns: code, name, price, taxable. "code" corresponds to items code, which is the primary key and also auto-increment, and taxable states weather the items is taxable or not. Currently i have the php page set up to display the database as well as 2 more columns with 1 column that allows the user to select the quantity of the item wanted, The other column adds an update cart button that should update the cart in a new table to the right of the one I just described. 
I need code for which ajax is used to update the table on the right in the php page. It should do only what i have described above: dynamically change the second table according to items and qty of items selected by the user.

Here is the database:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XU3we.png

here is the current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Groceries</title>
        <link href="shop_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>



            <div id='cont'>
                <?php
                $username = "amar";
                $password = "amar";
                $hostname = "localhost";
                $database = "study";

                $mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
                        or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

                $query = "select code, name, price, taxable from items";
                $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

                if (!$result) {
                    $message = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
                    die($message);
                }
                echo "<div id = left>";
                echo "<table border=1 cellpadding=2>";
                echo "<tr><td>Item Code: </td>";
                echo "<td>Description: </td>";
                echo "<td>Price: </td>";
                echo "<td colspan = 2>Taxable: </td>";
                echo "<td>Quatity</td>";
                echo "<td>Update Cart</td></tr>";

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

                    $code = $row['code'];
                    $desc = $row['name'];
                    $price = $row['price'];
                    $tax = $row['taxable'];

                    echo "<tr><td>";
                    echo $row['code'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['name'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    echo $row['price'];
                    echo "</td><td>";
                    if ($row['taxable'] == 'Y') {
                        echo "Yes";  
                    }
                    echo "</td><td>"; 
                    if ($row['taxable'] == 'N') {
                        echo "No";
                    }
                    echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td><input type=text name=qty" . $row['code'] . " value=1 size=4/></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type=button onclick=update_cart() value=Update name=update/></td></tr>";
                } 


                echo "</table>";
                echo "</div>";


                ?>
                <div id=right>
                    Test
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: sorry TL;DR! try formatting

Comment: I don't think you're getting code written for you in this forum. This is for questions and answers. Please ask a question if you have a specific problem.